# redirect fragment identifier in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to implement a redirect in .htaccess file to fix a canonical issue.
The following URL

```
http://domain.com/#get-started
```

contains a fragment identifier.

I need to redirect it to

```
http://domain.com/
```

I checked out this [site](http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?t=3912), but it doesn't seem to help.
Do you guys have a clue how to redirect this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: You can't: the fragment part of an URL is not send by the client to the server.

Comment: @julp For some reason my URL will retain the hash symbol when I load the page. If the client side doesn't send the fragment id. then how does it show when the page loads? Is the browser saving the # symbol?

Comment: Because of some Javascript? A redirection which do the opposite (the server can set a fragment for the client)?